# Cannot run protractor on Internet explorer 11

Tags: angularjs, node.js, testing, protractor, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to run my jasmine E2E tests on IE11 but with no luck or whatsoever.
I'm on Windows 8.1.
My config:

```
exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,

    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    // run in multiple browsers
    multiCapabilities:[
     //    {
     //        'browserName': 'chrome'
     //    },
        // {
     //        'browserName': 'firefox'
     //    },       
        {
           'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        }
    ],

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
    // protractor is called.
    specs: ['./**/*js'],

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters@1.0
        // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
        // this until inside the onPrepare function.
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
        );
    }
};
```

Chrome and Firefox work like a charm but IE gives me this:

```
Error: browserName (internet explorer) is not supported with directConnect.
```

IEDriverServer.exe is added to my path. I've did all the requred config: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Connecting Directly to Browser Drivers](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers) `directConnect` setting would work for Firefox and Chrome only:

> directConnect: true - Your test script communicates directly Chrome
>   Driver or Firefox Driver, bypassing any Selenium Server. If this is
>   true, settings for seleniumAddress and seleniumServerJar will be
>   ignored. **If you attempt to use a browser other than Chrome or Firefox
>   an error will be thrown**.

You need to remove/comment out `directConnect`:

```
exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities:[
        {
           'browserName': 'internet explorer'
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

---

FYI, you can actually leave `capabilities` defined alongside with `multiCapabilities`, but in this case `protractor` would simply ignore `capabilities` and use `multiCapabilities` ([docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#testing-against-multiple-browsers)).

Comment: You can find more information on http://protractorsupport.blogspot.com/2015/05/use-protractor-with-internet-explorer.html

Answer (score 0):

Your config file like this below

exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities: {
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    specs: ['example_spec.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
    };

Answer (score 0):

Direct connect supports Chrome and Firefox browsers. It doesn't do the same for Internet Explorer, though.

Comment: You copied someone else's answer as is. Please add some more information to tell us why your answer is different.