# Unable to start ChromeDriver-Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I have seen couple of other threads dealing with similar issue but not same. I am using direct connect to the browser and `ChromeDriver` occasionally fails to start with the following error. Looks like I can set some browser timeout in config file just cannot figure it out. the `conf.js` looks like

```
'use strict';

exports.config = {
    /* seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
     ** enables to connect to the browsers directly.
     ** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889488/cannot-run-protractor-on-internet-explorer-11
     */

    directConnect: true,
    specs: ['giftengHomePageTests.js'],

    multiCapabilities: [{
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    }, {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },

    /**
     * {
     * 'browserName': 'internet explorer'
     * }
     * */

    ],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        isVerbose: true
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

> [chrome #1] Using ChromeDriver directly...
>
> [chrome #1] ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
>
> [chrome #1] Error: listen EACCES

**Error Update**

I have ran these same tests multiple times and now got the failure on Firefox driver. It's very irregular

> "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 9.0.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js specs\smoke\conf.js
>   [launcher] Running 2 instances of WebDriver
>
> ---
>
> [firefox #2] PID: 5748
>   [firefox #2] Specs: e:\working\protractor-e2e\specs\smoke\giftengHomePageTests.js
>   [firefox #2] 
>   [firefox #2] Using FirefoxDriver directly...
>   [firefox #2] ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
>   [firefox #2] Error: listen EACCES
>   [firefox #2]     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>   [firefox #2]     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1112:19)
>   [firefox #2]     at listen (net.js:1155:10)
>   [firefox #2]     at Server.listen (net.js:1240:5)
>   [firefox #2]     at isFree (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net\portprober.js:165:10)
>   [firefox #2]     at findPort (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net\portprober.js:197:7)
>   [firefox #2]     at d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net\portprober.js:186:5
>   [firefox #2]     at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
>   [firefox #2]     at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
>   [firefox #2]     at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12)
>   [firefox #2] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
>   [firefox #2]     at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:155:22)
>   [firefox #2]     at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:129:30)
>   [firefox #2]     at new Driver (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:272:36)
>   [firefox #2]     at [object Object].DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\driverProviders\direct.js:75:16)
>   [firefox #2]     at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:180:37)
>   [firefox #2]     at d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.js:257:21
>   [firefox #2]     at _fulfilled (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
>   [firefox #2]     at self.promiseDispatch.done (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:826:30)
>   [firefox #2]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:759:13)
>   [firefox #2]     at d:\Users\Saifur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:573:44
>
> [launcher] Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
>   [launcher] 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
>
> ### ..
>
> [chrome #1] PID: 8084
>   [chrome #1] Specs: e:\working\protractor-e2e\specs\smoke\giftengHomePageTests.js
>   [chrome #1] 
>   [chrome #1] Using ChromeDriver directly...
>   [chrome #1] gifteng page
>   [chrome #1]   Should pop up sign in modal box - pass
>   [chrome #1] WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'welcome/gift.jpg')]") - the first result will be used
>   [chrome #1]   Should navigate to gifteng Give page - pass
>   [chrome #1] 
>   [chrome #1] 
>   [chrome #1] Finished in 7.522 seconds
>   [chrome #1] 2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures
>   [chrome #1] 
>   [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
>   [launcher] firefox #2 failed with exit code: 1
>   [launcher] chrome #1 passed
>   [launcher] overall: 1 process(es) failed to complete
>   [launcher] Process exited with error code 100
>
> Process finished with exit code 100

Comment: Could you please share how do you start `protractor` and post the complete traceback if possible? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for your response man. I have all the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/safrrhmn/protractor-e2e). My internet was down and I will try to grab the complete stacktrace

Comment: Thanks. Cloned and tried it out - no errors for me. Could you give me the output of the following 3 commands: `$ webdriver-manager status`, `$ which webdriver-manager` and `$ chromedriver --version`?

Comment: @alecxe Just ran all three and got `C:\working\protractor-e2e\protractor-e2e>webdriver-manager status
selenium standalone is not present
chromedriver is not present
IEDriver is not present

C:\working\protractor-e2e\protractor-e2e>which webdriver-manager
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\working\protractor-e2e\protractor-e2e>chromedriver --version
'chromedriver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` however my tests are running fine.

Comment: Also, I was getting the error on my home machine. Plus, That error was not happening always. It was very random

Comment: Thanks, sorry forgot you are on windows. What if you execute `webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: I ran that. I will repeat same steps as soon as I get home and will update. Thanks for your help dude

Comment: @alecxe updated with full error trace

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the same problem even on older firefox and protractor? Also, is it related to `directConnect` only? Please try with `directConnect: false`.

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for your reply. You are right. I downgraded both and ended up with same result. Just tried with `directConnect: false` but on second run ended up with same result

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the line where you tell your config where to find the chromeDriver:

```
exports.config = {
        directConnect: true,
        chromeDriver: '/chromedriver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe',
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **baseUrl** in your config file

```
directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    onComplete: null,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 500000,
    print: function () { }
  }
```

This might be the reason